# why does this code compile and run despite me declaring an automatic instance of incomplete type

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

Technically the code given below should not compile and run,as i have declared an automatic instance of incomplete data type, but it does.Please can somebody decode that for me.

```
 #include<iostream.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    void main()
    {
     class student;
     student s;

    getch();
    }


    class student 
    {

     int age;
     public:
     student();
     ~student();   
    };

    student::student()
{
 age=14;
}

student::~student()
{
 }`
```

Comment: Which compiler? Did it at least produce a warning?

Comment: gcc/clang reject it : [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aa3d7824efd64aa)

Comment: turbo c++, no it did not produce a warning

Comment: `<iostream.h>` is not conforming either afaik

Comment: In addition to your expected error: `<iostream.h>` instead of `<iostream>`, missing semi colon after `age`.

Comment: and when i tried to give an output using the constructor, the program run but did not show the output

Comment: it is windows operating system, thats why iostream.h

Comment: @srishti77714 .h syntax has no relation to being on windows operating system. Paste the exact code, int age is missing a semi-colon ```;``` while <iostream.h> is preferred syntax in turbo c++.

Comment: yeah i have corrected that , i missed it by mistake

Comment: in turbo c++ we have to write .h

Comment: Why is your indentation so messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not valid ISO C++.

Your compiler is probably accepting it because it is not an ISO C++ compiler.
It is a compiler for a pre-standard, early 1990s version of "C++".

ISO C++ came into existence in 1998. There is no point rationalising about what "technically" should or should not happen in a language you're not using.

Comment: it gives errors when i define a function other than the constructor

Comment: @srishti77714 you would need to ask someone who knows a lot about borland compilers and early c++. Instead just use a modern c++ compiler on windows or switch to linux where you can use updated gcc suite(g++).

Comment: `about borland compilers and early c++` At least Borland C++ 5.5 (made in 2000) rejects this. So it's rather about "early C++".